# Loading properties file from Weblogic Server inside Spring Bean Configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

I am developing a Web Application using Spring mvc using Weblogic-12.2.1 as
application server.I want to keep all the properties file in my application server.I have perform the following steps for this:

Created a project specific folder appConfig in following path:
**Oracle/Middleware/ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/wl_server/config/appConfig**

Placed the properties file named **commonConfig.properties** inside of it.

Have also edited **setDomainEnv.cmd** with following entry:

```
  if NOT "%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
    set EXT_POST_CLASSPATH=%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%\config\appConfig
    if NOT "%POST_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
       set POST_CLASSPATH=%POST_CLASSPATH%;%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%
    ) else (
       set POST_CLASSPATH=%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%
  )
)
```

Please find below my Spring bean configuration file for this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">

  <bean id="commonProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location" value="classpath:config/appConfig/commonConfig"/>
  </bean>
  </beans>
```

But during the deployment time it is throwing `FileNotFoundException`
Please find below exception stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/appConfig/commonConfig] cannot be opened because it does not exist

at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:154)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:161)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1911)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

> 

Anyone has any suitable solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="commonProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath*:config/appConfig/commonConfig"/>
</bean>
```

Above configuration ran successfully in weblogic server.